# How to validate filleds in mysql for date today and onwards?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use the following code

```
alter table Appointment ADD constraint chk_date check( AppointmentDate >= curdate());
```

However it gives the following error saying that curdate function is disallowed in check. -
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK6YS.png)

Comment: could you give the code for that? I don't know about triggers.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @IndraKumarS I need to validate AppontmentDate column of Appointment table which only allow to enter dates today and onwards.

Comment: *I need to validate AppontmentDate column of Appointment table which only allow to enter dates today and onwards.* This must be checked during INSERT only, not always. Even it is TRUE during INSERT then after a lot of days it become FALSE. And what must occur? The row should auto-delete? The data in the table should not match the constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only deterministic functions may be used in [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) expression. You cannot create such CHECK.

Use BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER check_AppointmentDate 
BEFORE INSERT
ON Appointment 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.AppointmentDate < CURRENT_DATE THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'AppointmentDate cannot be set in the past.';
END IF;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bc964fbaab469ec841e62be99db4efd

Comment: It says there's a syntax error in line 8. I am using MySQL

Comment: Also line 9 and 10 are highlighted in the editor

Comment: @KanishkaWithanawasam 1) Fiddle shows that the syntax is correct. So you do something incorrectly. 2) Always provide complete error message. 3) Maybe you forget about DELIMITER?

Comment: @KanishkaWithanawasam If it is possible that the table `Appointment` would be updated and AppointmentDate` would be altered then create similar BEFORE UPDATE trigger. If it is useful, of course...